How can I flush/clear clients browser local storage, session storage and cache without logout?
We actively store data in local storage, session storage and cache. Until user clicks on logout button we do not clear the any of these data and we do not make user force logout. How can we flush out the old data when we have new data to put into cache and local/session storage?
Below are the current ways to flush out old data and get new data

Manually clearing out cache and local storage works fine.
Opening the application in an Incognito window works fine.


You can clear the entire local/session storage:
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();

You can remove a specific item from local/session storage:
localStorage.removeItem("foo");
sessionStorage.removeItem("bar").

However, you can simply overwrite old data with new data.
As for the cache, it's not directly possible, but you have several options:
Auto clear cache from browser
How to programmatically empty browser cache?
